# Return top 1 value from UNION of two queries and assign it to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to assign variable directly by getting top 1 result from `UNION` of two queries?

```
declare @a varchar(3)

select top 1 @a = (select sifval
                from VALUTI
                where OZNVAL = 'EUR'
                union 
                select sifval
                from KURSNA
                where OZNVAL = 'EUR')
```

Executing this query returns error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value'. Is there other way to do this, without creating temporary tables?

Comment: @Larnu Why do you think that there is no need for subquery? My subquery is returning two values, how could I do what I need without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(3)
SELECT TOP 1 @A = SIFVAL FROM (SELECT SIFVAL
                FROM VALUTI
                WHERE OZNVAL = 'EUR'
                UNION 
                SELECT SIFVAL
                FROM KURSNA
                WHERE OZNVAL = 'EUR') T
SELECT @A
```

Comment: Select SELECT TOP 1 @A getting 0 as Value

Answer (score 3):

If you care about performance, you might consider:

```
declare @a varchar(3);

select @a = (select top 1 sifval from VALUTI where OZNVAL = 'EUR');

if @a is null begin
      select @a = (select top 1 sifval from KURSNA where OZNVAL = 'EUR');
end;
```

The use of `top` without `order by` is highly suspicious.

Comment: quoting `The use of top without order by is highly suspicious.`

Comment: @GordonLinoff You were right, I have added the order by part too. But the other guy solved my problem 1st so I have picked his answer, even I have voted for yours also. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
declare @a varchar(3);

SET @a = (SELECT top 1 sifval FROM(select sifval
                from VALUTI
                where OZNVAL = 'EUR'
                union 
                select sifval
                from KURSNA
                where OZNVAL = 'EUR') as T);
```

Comment: this results in error. `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.`

Comment: It's because of brackets

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This 
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(3)


SELECT @A= sifval 
FROM 
    (Select top 1 sifval 
     FROM VALUTI  where OZNVAL = 'EUR'
     UNION 
     Select  top 1  sifval
     FROM KURSNA
     WHERE OZNVAL = 'EUR')a


SELECT @A
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: It's the same solution as Munna Extreme posted, but thanks.

Comment: @nikname When I Select SELECT TOP 1 @A getting 0 as Value

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need the Top 1 actually, because since the Variable van store only 1 Value at a time, It will by default Take Top 1 even if you have not specified.

You Can Also Try the following methods

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(3);
SELECT @a = sifval
FROM 
(
    SELECT sifval
    FROM VALUTI
    WHERE OZNVAL = 'EUR'
    UNION
    SELECT sifval
    FROM KURSNA
    WHERE OZNVAL = 'EUR'
)q;
```

Or This

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(3);
SET @a =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 sifval
    FROM
    (
       SELECT sifval
       FROM VALUTI
       WHERE OZNVAL = 'EUR'
       UNION
       SELECT sifval
       FROM KURSNA
       WHERE OZNVAL = 'EUR'
    ) q
);
```